# How to access the file inside the project sub folders in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having multiple GoogleService-plist for different environment in my project. All the GoogleService-plist has the same name in different sub folders(Refer the below image). All I want is to access the GoogleService-plist path in run time? Could anyone help me with this? I have attached the folder structure image.

[image]]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409670-path

Comment: It depends on the version of Xcode especially whether the yellow folders are virtual groups or real folders.

Comment: @vadian , my Xcode version is 12.5.1 and these are the folder I added into my project. All I want is to access the different plist in runtime. Since the plist is inside subfolder I have no idea how to access it using below function.


func path(forResource name: String?, 
   ofType ext: String?, 
inDirectory subpath: String?) -> String?

Comment: Right-click on one of the *folders* and choose "Show in Finder". Are they really **folders**?

Comment: @QuangHà, Using ,func path(forResource name: String?, ofType ext: String?, inDirectory subpath: String?) -> String?  how can I get the path of (lets say) Bugs dev- Googleservice-plist

Comment: @vadian, These are the real folder. I Have these folders inside my project

Comment: @Dinesh just try, another approach is providing different plist name, like `GoogleService-Info-BugsDev.plist`

Comment: @QuangHà, If I use different names, this approach works fine.
But I wanna use same names, Is there any way to do with the same name in different sub folders

Answer (score 3):

It's recommended to prefer the URL related API over the path related API for example

```
let bugsDevURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", 
                                 withExtension "plist", 
                                 subdirectory: "/Firebase/BugsDev")
```

Comment: I tried this, and when I printed the bugsDevURL I get nill.

Comment: If the folders are real folders - as I asked twice - then the code is supposed to work.

Comment: I have no idea about real folder and virtual folder. What should I do to make this work? @vadian

Comment: Open the application bundle (to get the URL `print(Bundle.main.resourceURL)`) and  figure it out.